# Why can't I use my Stack Overflow account to access Android Stack Exchange?

Tags: support, login, authentication, auto-login

I have a Stack Overflow account.  My username is 'mdarwin' and I have the badge 'informed', whatever that means.

Now I want to ask a question on [Android Stack Exchange](https://android.stackexchange.com/) and for some reason it doesn't recognise my account and I had to log in with yahoo.

Then to ask this question, I had to login with yahoo again.

In what way is Stack Exchange a 'network' if there's no single sign-on?

---

In my SO account it shows I've been logged into SO since Dec 2011, so you'll forgive me if I've forgotten how I had logged in...

Now trying to visit [Android Stack Exchange](https://android.stackexchange.com/), it doesn't recognise me (even though I'm currently logged in here), and even password recovery doesn't work (to either email).   Why aren't login tokens shared between sites?

I just want to log into [Android Stack Exchange](https://android.stackexchange.com/) with my existing account.  But I still can't figure it out.

Comment: Well, what did you use to login to Stack Overflow?

Comment: There is no such status, you just got the [informed badge](http://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/2600/informed). There seems to be a problem with your associated accounts, what OpenID provider you use for Stack Overflow?

Answer (score 4):

You have *created* your `android` and `meta` accounts *today*. We don't create accounts and auto-log in on sites that you don't have an account on.

You create an account by logging in through your open-id provider. When you use the same provider/credentials on separate sites, we link those accounts - this can be seen in your profile page (in the Accounts section).

There was no way to log you in to these sites before you created accounts on them - not that you need an account to ask questions and answer them (except for Stack Overflow).

Answer (score 0):

It is a single sign on, your accounts are linked across the network as long as you use the same OpenID (Yahoo, Google, Stack Exchange, etc). You can add more associated OpenIDs by following the instructions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/contact/edit-logins).

So, use whatever credentials (Yahoo/Google/SE/whatever) you use for SO to log in to Android.SE, and it will automatically link the accounts.

Once you have an associated account, logins will usually be automatic. As in, on visiting android.SE the next time, you ought to either be logged in or get a banner that will log you in.

Comment: I have no idea how I log in to stackoverflow - I'm there so often I've never been asked to log in again.  How can I find out how I'm logging in?

Comment: @MattDarwin Go to your profile on SO, and click "my logins". It will display details of your login credentials.